# How should I apply the git-flow paradigm to my project?

Tags: git, branch, git-flow

I have started to use git flow and have some questions.

1. In examples like [here](http://yakiloo.com/getting-started-git-flow/) and [here](https://www.lucidchart.com/community/examples/view/4d454c50-6b0c-47eb-9238-11040ad09a4f) I see a release branch started and then several commits done before the release branch gets finished. Why is that? 
   Shouldn't everything be ready and then being released? In the first example there is even a new feature developed while the release branch is open.
2. I am about to do some refactoring to my current project. What branch should I use/create? A feature branch seems not right to me because it's no feature as per definition. Should I do it right in the development branch?
3. As far as I have seen and read, feature branches are local only but what if I want to develop a feature with a whole team?

Comment: Oh I forgot a third question:

3. As far as I have seen and read, feature branches are local only but what if I want to develop a feature with a whole team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Two things

   - **Administrative Changes** - This is where you might do things like bump the version number in your application and documentation. The premise is that until you make the branch, you don't know what the [next version number](http://semver.org/) will be, so you defer that decision.
   - **Bugfixes** - You're done with all the features you want in the release, but there are some bugfixes coming. You can either tell everyone not to merge feature branches (intended for a future release) into development until the release is done or start the release branch allowing development to move forward.
2. Feature branches for everything. *Feature branch* is just a name; they're more like *do some work without messing up everyone else* branches, but that's a long name.
3. It's perfectly reasonably to share feature branches. Ask your co-workers about their preferences.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer and also for the link. I didn't know about semantic versioning before.